# SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert access denied connect to bitbucket

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls

I have trouble, my ubuntu don't connect to bitbucket.org by https.
I install newsletter openssl version

```
kodix@n-kdx-30:~/tmp$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
```

but error don't desappear. If I request resource by curl

> curl -v https://bitbucket.org

I get this response

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://bitbucket.org/
*   Trying 18.205.93.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to bitbucket.org (18.205.93.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:14094419:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert access denied
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:14094419:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert access denied
```

I try update/upgrade system, update openssl, enable ssl v2 and v3, and other, but I can't get success result. Sory for my English, I hope you understand me, and can help solve my problem.